# Vue.js - Disable Transitions on Child Div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions

I have a situation where I need to be able to disable the fade transition on a child div within a `<transition>` component. The reason why it must be nested is due to the layout flickering when it's not nested (can provide a fiddle for this as well if needed).

If you see the below fiddle, what I want to do is when you hover over red, the non-dynamic text immediately disappears from blue, and vice versa, however, currently it transitions out rather than just disappearing. I've also tried with `v-if` and `v-show` which of course still trigger the fade transition.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/humni/eywraw8t/544985/)

Check the fiddle for the whole example, the sample below gives a general idea of what I'm needing

```html
<template>
  <transition name="fade" mode="in-out">
    <div :key="dynamicTitle">
      <h1>{{ dynamicTitle }}</h1>
      <div v-if="dynamicTitle != 'title'">
        <p>static content which should immediately disapear, but doesn't</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template
```

Comment: maybe you can use 'onmouseenter' and 'onmouseleave' events instead of 'hover' to achieve asymmetric behavior

Comment: @KevinHe I already am using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by modifying your CSS

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .0s;
}
```

modified fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld9mqe2u/)

Comment: This actually removes the entire transition fade in

Comment: yes, I updated the answer and included a modified fiddle for You.. thanks for commenting.

Comment: For more context, the `dynamicTitle` is actually a dynamic image in the real implementation, which should fade in overtop (including the static content area), however, this solution removes that transition.

Comment: then it makes sence to use 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave', sepperating the `.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active` css rules makes it flicker..